# How to ping a websocket server every 1 second in JS

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to create a javascript code (it is not node js) that sends a message every 1 second, like a ping.

```js
ws1 = new WebSocket("wss://site.com/support_ws")
console.log("[start]")

function banana(){
    console.log("sending ws1")
    ws1.send(`{"type":"ping","message":"[WebSocket: wss://site.com/support_ws]: ping"}`); // THIS SEND DOESN'T WORK.
}


ws1.onopen = function(event){
    console.log("ws1 connected!")
    ws1.send(`{"type":"ping","message":"[WebSocket: wss://site.com/support_ws]: ping"}`); // THIS SEND WORKS FINE
    setInterval(banana, 1000) // every 1 second it calls function to send the ping
}

ws1.onmessage = function(event){
    console.log("ws1 - " + event.data)
}
ws1.onerror = function(error) {
  alert(`[error] ` + error.message);
};
```

But my websocket get disconnected when I try to send() in the function banana (every 1 sec).I get the error
[WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ooC8.png) on js console.

I would like to know how to fix it and why it happens.

Comment: Please add the code for your websocket server. Without it, there's no way for us to know if it's the server that isn't working as intended.

Comment: Create another function with `ws1.onclose` and check if it is getting closed. From the post i can tell that the websocket is already closed and you cannot send anything on a closed websocket.

Comment: Actually, I don't own the server. I am trying to build a Web-socket CSRF proof of concepts exploit so I can report it. Their server is working fine with a python script and it isn't closing the connection.